# VB: Open as Read-Only File

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am working on a program that involved that use Excel VBA as part of my VB Program. I created a program that will open the workbook containing the macro and run it. But for some reason, the vb open the workbook as read-only file. I don't want the workbook to open as read-only file. Below is the code that I used to open the workbook:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Public Class chart_Display

Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim oBooks As Excel.Workbooks
Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Sub runMacro()

    'Start Excel and open the workbook containing macro
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oExcel.Visible = False
    oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks
    oBook = oBooks.Open("C:\Users\Joesph\Documents\Cynthia's Folder\Experiment\Testing Files\Test3.xlsm")

    'Run the macro
    oExcel.Run("Get18x17_14mil")
    oBook.Save()

End Sub
End Class
```

I have timer that will run the macro every x minutes and it will create a line chart. The program will continue looping until the user exit the program.
I used this code before for my other program and it working just fine. I don't get why. Please help me as I'm still inexperience with VB. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the workbook you are trying to open is closed?

Comment: Yeah, i have a code at the end to close it before re-opening it.

Comment: Check in Task Manager for hidden instances of Excel, one of those might have a lock on the file.

Comment: agreed with Tim. However, are you certain you have write access to folder where your file reside?

Comment: I did what @TimWilliams said, and it still opening up as read-only file. I actually need to add `oSheet = Nothing` to prevent the workbook from locking, but if I mess the code it will lock up on me again.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure it is not thread-issue as others have mentioned it in the comments. The easiest way is to create a copy of that file just before oBooks.Open() and work with that copy.

Another issue might be the path: 
You usually need admin rights to access files inside C:\Users on windows. Make sure you have them. Try to open the file from another location to make sure this isn't the issue here.